# What exactly laravel's isValid method does?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I was reading the Laravel's docs and I've stumbled upon this isValid() method, that returns TRUE or FALSE whether the file is valid or not.

But... What this method actually does? I know it returns TRUE or FALSE, but what is behind this check? Over what is checking if is valid or not? I've googled for a while but can't really find something useful...

Can you guys explain me this?

Thanks!

Comment: In what regard? File upload?

Comment: What do you mean _what this method actually does_ do you mean the code behind the method? You've pretty much said what _it does_ returning true/false if a file is valid or not.. what _exactly_ are you after?

Comment: http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html#method_isValid

Comment: Looking at its source, it checks PHP's `is_uploaded_file` and for an error code in the file's data.

Comment: Oh, sorry in fact i didn't explain it so well. Yes, what i was wondering it was the code behind it. So thanks @ceejayoz for the answer. It was exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: @ceejayoz where is the source cause i looked every where for `$request->file('file_input_name')->isValid()`

Comment: @BobbyAxe I linked to the file in the comments above. http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html#method_isValid

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks a lot, my suspicions were right it was just wrapping `is_uploaded_file()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means if there is no errors ocurred during the file upload process either by OS/WebServer/php i.e. it has moved to the temporary location successfully

Comment: OK now that make sense! Thank you!